# how to make multiple selections in DOS config.sys with submenus?

Tags: ms-dos

here is what I am trying to accomplish:

when booting DOS, using config.sys,

have a selection of CD drivers to choose from

AND

have a selection of USB drivers to choose from

AND

choose between load EMM386 or not

AND

choose between load mouse driver or not

any ONE of those can be done with a menu. but not ALL of them.

if you try making a submenu for each one, that's fine, but the moment you select anything, that selection gets run and DOS starts. you didn't get to make the other choices too.

if there is a way to [make a selection and load a driver] then return to the main menu, that would be the right way to approach this, but I don't know how to do it. as far as I know you can't do it.

INCLUDE=MENU doesn't work. SUBMENU=MENU dosn't work unless you're already in the menu and haven't made any choices yet. you can't copy another menu structure below the first one because once you make a choice and it loads a driver, it ignores any other [MENU] structure that comes later on.

I even tried having a selection set a value instead of loading a driver with the idea that the menu can have a final selection of "commit" where it goes to a final block and uses if/then to load drivers, but that didn't work because you still can't make it return to the main menu for anything.

how can this be done?

Comment: probably you'll want to ask this on [retrocomputing.se]

Comment: MS-DOS have no this possibility. You can: 1) Create 16 menu elements (each element = some combination of options); 2) Build 4 submenu pairs (each pair with separate optoin selection) and build the selection chain from them. 3) Create your own executable loaded as a non-TSR device driver which performs draw the menu with enable/disable multi-selections and executions you need.